# How to change the file's permission and last modified in Java?

Tags: java, file, permissions, cross-platform, last-modified

To my knowledge, Java's File class does not support to change the file's permission and last modified date. Is there any proper way to do this in a cross-platform style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm looking at the [Java 6 documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/), and there is a `setLastModified()` method, as well as `setReadable(...)` and `setWritable(...)` and `setExecutable(...)` methods (all in the `java.io.File` class).  So yes, there is a way...

Comment: Other than setLastModified and setReadOnly, which were in Java 1.2, the others were added in 1.6