# How to create a file with public read write access Using Java

Tags: java, file-io

How would I set write access to file and to all users using Java version 1.4? I know we can do this using the `setWritable()` method which is available in Java 1.6 onward. We can also do this operation by executing the Linux command "`chmod`" using RunTime method.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Java 5 has been [EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) for 5 years!  Why are you targeting Java 1.4?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I have tried it with executing Linux command.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, we have server which has Java 1.4 version and this causes me to stay in Java 1.4

Comment: @JavaKK Sun wouldn't support it before Oracle bought them, and Oracle certainly won't support it now. I'm sorry your organization won't upgrade to supported software. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change file permissions from Java 1.4.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464391/how-to-change-file-permissions-from-java-1-4-2)

Comment: If you start your program with `umask 002` it will automatically create world-readable files. I dont think it is a good idea to create world writeable files.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing possible from 1.4 is

```
Runtime.exec("chmod ...")
```

See more at

1. [How to change file permissions from Java 1.4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464391/how-to-change-file-permissions-from-java-1-4-2)